# Changing boot order ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I am facing problems in dual-boot `ubuntu` and `windows 10`. Upon reboot system boots into windows rather than starting `ubuntu grub`. I tried to change the `bootorder` using `efibootmgr`. This was before changing the order-

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 3003,3000,3001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Ubuntu
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

I tried this `command` -
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,1,3

This is the order after-

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003
Boot0000* Ubuntu
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

But when I reboot, boot order again reverses to the original one and therefore,windows opens by default.
So, how can I change this boot order permanently.

Answer (score 1):

First boot into your Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.
Disable hibernation by opening **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
    powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

**Shut down** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

Reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - open a terminal and execute:

```
    sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
    for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
    sudo chroot /mnt
    grub-install /dev/sd*
    update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted**, the tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in **UEFI settings** to be the default operating system to boot.
Now you are able to select the operating system you want to boot from the **GRUB boot menu**.

Comment: Ok what I understand is `sd***` means the `ext4` partition where my ubuntu is installed,, `sd**` is the boot partition but what is sd*?

Comment: @Joker : yes - and sd* is the "whole - main - disk" ... in most of the cases it is sda (the first disk). :)

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work. Still system directly loads windows

Comment: @Joker : Please check again whether hibernation and fast boot is disabled - otherwise it will always boot into Windows ... and please check whether you can disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology in BIOS/UEFI settings - if not, disable it ! :)

Comment: Yes I checked both hibernation and fast boot are disabled. No, there is no option to disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology

Comment: @Joker : There is another option you can try - Boot into Windows - Open command prompt as administrator - enter : bcdedit /enum all /v - select the ubuntu identifier and set this as default. :)

Comment: Sorry but can you please tell me how to select and set as default. This is the result of the cmd u mentioned-http://pastie.org/private/w3lfmgp50wextuvr5cjgyw

Comment: @Joker : Looks a little bit "messed up" what I see ... Do no not use 3rd party tools like boot-repair ! 1. try : bcdedit /default {6a3ea96c-81b0-11e5-8eb9-b47fae3d91ac} - when not working ... 2. try : bcdedit /default {c6dc37cf-81b8-11e5-9bc5-806e6f6e6963} - good luck my friend ! :)

Comment: Sorry but none of them is working. I think I will have to switch back to windows 8+ubuntu dual boot. It used to work fine.

Comment: @Joker : My suggestion - if possible for you - erase the disk and make a clean install of both systems ... hope I could help you anyway ... :)

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Joker : You're welcome ! You nevertheless have to follow the instructions given in my answer ... disable hibernation and fast boot after installing Windows and then after that ... install Ubuntu ... so if you think this helped you can consider to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when installing Ubuntu/Win7 dual boot. Rather than showing Grub, it skips straight into Windows. However, there was an easy solution for me: use Boot-Repair to fix Grub. The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to boot into a live session of Ubuntu from a bootable CD or USB, and then install Boot-Repair and then run it. Reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for how to do that. Changing the boot order probably won't work because Grub is not even being launched, which is the issue.

Comment: Sorry but this is also not working